# Restricting decimal places / milliseconds positions in an XML schema's dateTime elements?

Tags: regex, xml, datetime, xsd

How can an XML schema restrict the number of milliseconds (the decimal places used for the seconds position) in elements with the base type xs:dateTime ?

Is it as simple as defining a content model that restricts xs:dateTime?

1. The only options I had found in the XSD specification were for restricting the *value* of the dateTime content, not its *format*, however.
2. Then I discovered a valid XSD snippet with a restriction:

`<xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
<xs:pattern value=".*Z"/>
</xs:restriction>`

- This is taken directly from a valid XML Schema instance (i.e. it validates in the xs namespace)
- Please see also samples 35 - 38 from this O'Reilly XML book:

http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596002527/patterns.html

3. Finally got this regular expression:

`^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T(00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):(0[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])((\.)\d\d\d)?(Z|(\+(00|0[0-9]|1[0-4]):(0[0-9]|[0-5][0-9]))|(\-(00|0[0-9]|1[0-2]):(0[0-9]|[0-5][0-9])))?$`

Apart from the fact that XML regex does not need ^$ to mark up the string to be matched, is this going to work in the finished .xsd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with this XSD restriction, because I also needed the timezone to be included and in a specific format:

`<xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
            <xs:pattern
                value="([^\.]*|([^\.]*(\.((\d){1,3})){0,1}))(Z|\+([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])|-([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]))"
            />
        </xs:restriction>`

Answer (score 1):

The format for xs:dateTime is specified in the spec in [dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) and further explained in [isoformats](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats). The format **is defined** as:

```
'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss ('.' s+)? (zzzzzz)?
```

As you can see fractional seconds are optional and of arbitrary precision. There is no way to enforce another format or to fix the number of decimals.

Comment: Hello @cma, that is what I thought, too, but then I saw some examples such as:

`<xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
            <xs:pattern value=".*Z"/>
        </xs:restriction>`

Comment: Then maybe you can try something like `<xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime"> <xs:pattern value="'-'? yyyy '-' mm '-' dd 'T' hh ':' mm ':' ss.sss (zzzzzz)?"/> </xs:restriction>` to have 3 decimals, if that's you goal.